# Bold table column generated from php

Tags: php, jquery, arrays, html-table

I am trying to bold the content of the last column of my table, not sure how to select those key values and apply a bold, very new with jquery.

```
<?php        
    $items = array(
        array("City" => "Dalas","Age" => "47", "Name" => "Janet Fuller", "Address" => "445 Upland Pl.", "Status" => "Trial"),
        array("City" => "Lyon", "Age" => "38", "Name" => "Andrew Heiniger", "Address" => "347 College Av.", "Status" => "Active"),
        array("City" => "Dallas", "Age" => "43", "Name" => "Susanne Smith", "Address" => "2 Upland Pl.", "Status" => "Active"),
        array("City" => "Paris", "Age" => "25", "Name" => "Sylvia Steel", "Address" => "269 College Av.", "Status" => "Suspended"),
        array("City" => "San Francisco", "Age" => "7", "Name" => "James Peterson", "Address" => "231 Upland Pl.", "Status" => "Active"),
        array("City" => "Oslo", "Age" => "42", "Name" => "Robert Ott", "Address" => "503 Seventh Av.", "Status" => "Trial")
    );
?>

    <?php if (count($items) > 0): ?>
       <table>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th><?php echo implode('</th><th>', array_keys(current($items))); ?></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
     <?php foreach ($items as $row): array_map('htmlentities', $row); ?>
            <tr>
              <td><?php echo implode('</td><td>', $row); ?></td>
            </tr>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Styling content in web pages (if that is what you mean by "bold") is usually not done via logic, be it client or server side, but by means of style sheets, so css files.

Comment: I dont think I can select the key "Status" and set the values to bold, in css.

Comment: There are selectors like `:last-child` which you can apply to the table cells...

Comment: would $("td:last-child").css("font-weight:", "bold"); work?

Comment: You head into the right direction, but as said: you do not want to do that per client side logic, so in javascript. Why would you want to do that? Use a css file. Easier and more efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use css:

```css
#myTable td:last-child {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>first</th>
      <th>last</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>first</td>
      <td>last</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
      <td>first</td>
      <td>last</td>
    </tr> 
  </tbody>
</table>
```